# Write to Netty channel from other application threads

Tags: networking, netty

I have a TCP server read from client and write the response to client using handler. 
Besides that, my server  has a scheduler thread needs write to all connected clients some messages periodically.

Is it safe to call channel.write() method from the scheduler thread? do I have to implement lock when write to the channel this non-netty thread?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe... All operations will be dispatched to the `EventLoop` thread.